# Uploading images from android app to azure blob services using RESTful web api

Tags: android, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

I want to do an Android app that upload/download some images to/from Azure blob storage using web api. Can anyone suggest me some valid guide, examples or tutorials that help me to  understand how to use these technologies to do my application?

Answer (score 1):

Start at [Azure documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) for your language of choice.  Then read the [Storage Services REST API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179355).  Then under the documentation, check out the Samples - for example - [Samples that show how to use Mobile Services as a backend for your Android apps](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/android-samples/), and more specifically: [Android - Mobile Services - StorageDemo](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Samples/Android-MobileServices-Storage) on the samples page.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start with this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) then I'll follow the azure documentation and the Storage Services REST API Ref. I've already seen the Mobile Services but I did not use them because they need the azure account and I have not it; I'd prefer to use the local storage emulator and run the app in local without publishing it. What I want to do is, from the android app, make an http request (GET/POST) to the web app and put or receive data (images) in JSON format from the cloud storage.